# Непонятная ошибка в Yii

Tags: php, yii

Нашёл интересный момент в Yii.
Переопределил конструктор:

```
class Object extends CActiveRecord
{   
    public function __construct($scenario='insert')
    {
        $this->setFilesDirectory();
        return parent::construct($scenario);
    }
}
```

Получил ошибку:

```
[Tue Jan 14 12:23:10 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /var/www/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php on line 402, referer: http://localhost/object/add
```

Могу весь стектрейс выложит, но, думаю, не нужно.
В чём я не прав?
Может в Yii конструктор нельзя переопределять?

Comment: а зачем вы возвращаете parent::construct($scenario)? Попробуйте без `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где-то у вас оно радостно зациклилось в рекурсии. 
Конструкторы и любые магические методы лучше в Yii вообще не трогать, используйте триггеры (afterFind, afterSave) и всевозможные init.

Comment: А чем плох onAfterSave ?

Comment: Ничем, например, его и надо использовать.
UPD: ни фига. onAfterSave - это эвент, а afterSave - метод. Используем именно afterSave.